# How to import data with line breaks from text file into R?

Tags: r, input, text-files

I have a text file that I'd like to import into `R`. Problem is, the file looks like this:

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,10,x11
   1953.00       7.40000       159565.       16.6680       8883.00    
   47.2000       26.7000       16.8000       37.7000       29.7000    
   19.4000    
   1954.00       7.80000       162391.       17.0290       8685.00    
   46.5000       22.7000       18.0000       36.8000       29.7000    
   20.0000
```

and so on.

I tried `> data <- read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)` but that didn't work.

Comment: Some clarification.  The header is a single comma-separated string and the data itself is whitespace delimited?

Comment: I suppose that you read help to `read.table` and try some options like separator, fill, etc. You could copy&paste error message, 'didn't work' don't tell much. Maybe you computer is off ;)

Comment: what's the problem exactly? Is the first data line on the same line as the headers?

Answer (score 5):

While the data is ill-formed it still can be parsed given the following assumptions:

- The header defines how many variables there are (columns in the resultant table)
- The data itself is complete - e.g. there are no missing values
- The data is of a uniform type (e.g. `numeric()`)

The following is code that parses the provided sample data as if it were read in from a text file called `data.txt`:

```
# read in the header and split on ","
header = strsplit(readLines('data.txt', n=1), ',')[[1]]

# the length of the header determines how many variables there are

# read in the data which appears to have the pattern
#   <numbers><whitespace><numbers>...
# skipping the first line since it was already parsed as the header
data = scan('data.txt', skip=1, what=numeric())

# reform the data (which is read in as a 1D numeric vector) into a 2D matrix
# with the same number of columns as there are headers (filling by rows).
# header names are assigned via the `dimnames=` argument
data = matrix(data, ncol=length(header), byrow=T, dimnames=list(NULL, header))
```

producing the following output:

```
       x1  x2     x3     x4   x5   x6   x7   x8   x9  x10  x11
[1,] 1953 7.4 159565 16.668 8883 47.2 26.7 16.8 37.7 29.7 19.4
[2,] 1954 7.8 162391 17.029 8685 46.5 22.7 18.0 36.8 29.7 20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could manually edit the first line (change , to " " and insert a line break) and then try again?

Comment: The read.csv command sort of worked, but instead of returning all variables values for an observation on one line (which is what I want), variable values for each observation spill over two lines (which is what I don't want). tricky

Comment: so it seems one observation is on 3 lines. I don't think this can be handled by read.csv. Maybe you could try ?readLines, and then run a for loop to concatenate the data for each observation?

Answer (score -1):

Use `read.csv` instead of `read.table` and then add `skip=1, header=FALSE` to the arguments to `read.csv`.